# jQuery center rotating image in div horizontally and vertically using .position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my fiddle example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwuliger/jSXNm/

I am trying to get the image to be centered in my container div using the .position UI method.

```
 $draggable.position({ of: $canvas, my: 'center', at: 'center' });
```

Can someone please help me get this image to stay centered both horizontally and vertically in the canvas div as it rotates? Specifically at angle 90 & 270.

It is not working. Any other solution would OK as well!

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

To get the image to rotate click on the image.

Comment: In your jsFiddle I'm not sure how to get the canvas to rotate to 90 or 270 degrees.

Comment: Sorry about that I should have made that clear. Click on the image.

Comment: Fiddle no longer exists - please remove this question.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/jwuliger/jSXNm/1/

I just played with the margins:

```
 var canvasWidth = parseInt($("." + $canvas.attr("class").replace(" ", ".")).width());
 var canvasHeight = parseInt($("." + $canvas.attr("class").replace(" ", ".")).height());
 var offsetLeft = (canvasWidth - $draggable.width()) / 2;
 var offsetTop = (canvasHeight - $draggable.height()) / 2;
 $draggable.css({ 'margin-top': offsetTop - 2, 'margin-left': offsetLeft });
```

Comment: Fiddle with solution deleted. -1